# Programmatic UIButton as a subview of UIView is not responding

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, subview

I'm making a class that extends UITableViewCell--it's going to display a social media newsfeed, with each cell being someone's post.

I've added a UIButton as a subview of a UIView, So the UIView will contain both the button and a label as subviews, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhvRF.png). (Sorry the image is kind of small but I think you'll get the idea of it).

However, the UIButton isn't responding to taps, not even highlighted. Its superview itself has a number of superviews, all stacks, but I checked and every superview's isUserInteractionEnabled is true.

```
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button(UIImage(named: "vertical_dots")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = .white
    button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myButtonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    
    label.text = "\(userPost?.minutesAgo)m"
    label.font = label.font.withSize(11.0)
    label.textColor = .lightGray
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.numberOfLines = 1
    
    let superview = UIView()
    superview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    superview.addSubview(button)
    superview.addSubview(label)
    
    label.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
    label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    button.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
    button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 15).isActive = true
```

I'm getting a lot of constraint warning but I don't think that would affect things?

Note that this is only a chunk of my code, and I am adding the superview to other views, but I'm not showing all that here. None of my views have frames, only constraints, and they're all appearing correctly.

I don't think this question has been asked before because others are working with Interface Builder, while I'm doing it all programmatically.

Comment: Won't my constraints overwrite that though?

Comment: You have not added subview to view

Comment: I do that later in the code but don't show it here, I'll add that note to my post

Comment: Yeah I noticed that about the superview, how it doesn't have a frame, but the views still appear correctly in the app. None of my views have frames bc of the constraints I set for them--is that bad? They're all appearing as I want them to

Comment: You added superview to TableViewCell and set constraints to it.
Do you even see button & label currently? I guess question should be that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the constraints you've shown, you cannot tap your button because it is outside the bounds of your `superview`.

To confirm this, add this line:

```
superview.clipsToBounds = true
```

and you almost certainly won't even **see** your button or label.

You need to either give `superview` width and height constraints, or you need to add constraints so the subview(s) determine the superview's bounds.

For example, add these lines:

```
    label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.topAnchor).isActive = true
    label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    button.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.rightAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that the table view cell thinks it is being selected and is cancelling the touch of the button.

Try this:

```
tableView.allowsSelection = false
```

If that's not the case, try checking the frame of your button to see if you're actually tapping on it. You can [use the Debug View Hierarchy button](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015022-CH9-SW2) to check this.

Furthermore, you can try:

```
button.clipSubviews = true
```

If you can't see your button, then the frame is wrong, and you can't tap outside of the frame of a button. (Even if you can see it.)

Comment: Hmm I tried that but I'm still getting the same result. I appreciate the suggestion though.

Comment: Have you made sure that the button has isUserInteractionEnabled set to true?

Comment: Maybe check the frame of the button to make sure you're actually tapping on it? (And not an image that may reach beyond the bounds of the button.)

Comment: Yeah I checked that, it's true. And all the superviews are also true

Comment: I think that might be the problem, that I haven't given it a frame. But when I assign it a CGRect for the frame, I still get the same result. My guess is that my constraints are causing a problem?